# Inverse function for a surface of revolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse

I have the following function:

$$
f(x)= c_1\cdot c_2\cdot x\cdot \arctan\left(c_2\cdot x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\cdot c_1\cdot \ln\left(1+c_2^2\cdot x^2\right)
$$

with $c_1=0.003$ and $c_2=150$ constants and $x \in [-0.035,0.035]$. The function represents a line, that when revolved around $y$ gives the surface of a mirror.

I would like to find the radius of the mirror from the axis of revolution (i.e. $x$-value in 2D) as a function of the height (i.e. $y$ or $f(x)$). The way I thought of approaching this problem is by inverting the function, however this doesn't seem to be possible.

What would be a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: The radius is $y$, and it varies for each point. There's no single radius.

Comment: Is it like a parabolic mirror, its derivation is required? Are there any references? We may need to derive a special ODE for numerical integration.

Comment: Yes, it is like a parabolic mirror. The center of the mirror is parabolic shaped and the more you move towards the outside, the mirror is more cone shaped.
I don't have any references.